# Using DISTINCT and TOP in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use `DISTINCT` and `TOP` in the same query. I tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 * FROM TableA
```

but I still have a duplicate `personID`, so I tought to do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (personID) TOP 10 * FROM TableA
```

But here the syntax is wrong. How do I do it correctly?

Comment: What will you do if you want to choose only one `personID` if you have duplicate rows?

Answer (score 79):

You're using a `SELECT *` which is pulling in all records. If you want to use a true DISTINCT only list out the column you want to receive distinct values of. If you have multiple columns then all those columns combined make up one distinct record.

```
SELECT distinct TOP 10 personID 
FROM TableA
```

Note that without an `ORDER BY` this will return the first 10 records in no particular order. The results could be different each time you run the query.

Answer (score 11):

You seem to want 10 random records for different persons.  Try this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
```

In general, though, when using `top` you should also be using an `order by` to specify what you mean by "top".

Answer (score 11):

It works simply if you use query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 2 name FROM [ATTENDANCE] ;
```

In the above query, `name` is the column_name and `[ATTENDANCE]` is the table_name.

You can also use `WHERE` with this to make filtering conditions.

Answer (score 4):

select distinct personid from tablea sample 10

This works in teradata

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 t.* FROM (SELECT distinct personID FROM TableA) t
```

Answer (score 1):

Few options:

1:
SELECT  TOP 10 personID
FROM (SELECT distinct personID FROM  TableA)

2:
;with cte as
(SELECT distinct personID FROM TableA)
SELECT top 10 personID FROM cte

3:
;with cte as
(SELECT personID,row_count=row_number() over (partition by personID order by personID)
FROM TableA
) SELECT top 10 personID FROM cte where row_count=1

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question, but I can suggest a more **elegant solution**:

```
SELECT personDetails.*
FROM
(
    SELECT      TOP (10)
                personID
                personID
    FROM        TableA
    GROUP BY    personID    --> use this instead of distinct
)   AS          distinctIds

OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT  TOP (1) *       --> fetch only one result matching personID
    FROM    TableA
    WHERE   TableA.personId = distinctIds.personID
)   AS      personDetails
```

You can use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, and you can use OUTER APPLY with TOP(1) to fetch only one matching result.

Comment: IMO definitely not more elegant that Matt Busche's solution (which should be the answer).  Unless you put it in a fancy font maybe :)

Comment: @8forty , the solution of Matt Busche returns only the personID, while the solution I provided gives back all the fields (select *)

Answer (score 0):

The Matt Busche answer is correct based on the post title.
But if, as it seems from your code examples, your problem is to have all the record fields from the distinct top 10 personID, you can use that as a subquery:

```
SELECT TableA.* 
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 personID FROM TableA) AS B
ON TableA.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering an older question but...if the goal is to get ten records with no more than one per person id:

```
    select top 1 with ties *
      from TableA
     order by row_number() over (partition by PersonId order by PersonId)
```

you can use different columns for the "inner" order by to prioritize the selection; doing it as is will more or less randomly select one row per personID

Answer (score -1):

`SELECT DISTINCT ta.personid FROM (SELECT  TOP 10 * FROM TableA) ta`

ta is object of subquery and using ta object we can distinct the values

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, can you add a brief description of the code you posted here? Just posting code is usually not appreciated at SO.

Comment: add details/description related to your answer. check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This is not a good solution- the subquery (with top 10) might give you 10 rows of the same personID, which will result in having 1 row in the resultset

Answer (score -3):

i fixed it i did

```
select distinct  personid from (SELECT  TOP 10 * FROM TableA)
```

Comment: Without an order by results may vary.  Even a table with PK is not guaranteed to return the same order without an order by.

Comment: if you have the same personid in your top 10 results then this won't work, you would only get 9 results. It's as simple as `SELECT distinct TOP 10 personID FROM TableA`

Answer (score -3):

If the goal is to select the top 1 record of every personID, then use

```
select * from TableA group by personid
```

Since you are doing a "group by", it will return every column, but will ignore (not display) any additional rows with the same personId

Comment: This will not work in sql-server, it will result with an error