# MSSQL: use DISTINCT, TOP selection without a GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, left-join

I want to use DISTINCT and TOP selection without a GROUP BY clause.

I want to select rows from [locations] and order the results by the number of rows are associated with each location in [location_photos]

I now have this (not even using TOP):

```
SELECT distinct(l.id),count(lp.locationid) OVER(partition by l.id) AS photos
,ISNULL(lp.locpath,'') as thumb
,l.id,l.title
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN location_photos lp on lp.locationid=l.id
ORDER BY photos desc
```

This however returns a row for each row in [location_photos] (56,000), where this should be a potential maximum of the number of rows in [locations] (12,000).

I already checked [here](https://www.codeexplained.net/use-count-sql-without-group-clause/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479224/using-distinct-and-top-at-the-same-time/15479244).

How can I select the distinct number of rows using DISTINCT and TOP?

**DDL and data**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locations](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [createdate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_locs] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[locations] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_homes_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[location_photos](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [locationid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [locpath] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_location_photos] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_photos]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_locs_photos_homes] FOREIGN KEY([locationid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[locations] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_photos] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_locs_photos_homes]
GO



INSERT INTO [locations](id,title) VALUES (1,'new york')
INSERT INTO [locations](id,title) VALUES (2,'boston')
INSERT INTO [locations](id,title) VALUES (3,'chicago')
INSERT INTO [locations](id,title) VALUES (4,'los angeles')


INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (1,'nyc1')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (1,'nyc2')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (1,'nyc3')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (1,'nyc4')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (1,'nyc5')

INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (2,'boston1')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (2,'boston2')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (2,'boston3')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (2,'boston4')

--there are not photos for chicago on purpose

INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (4,'la1')
INSERT INTO [location_photos](locationid,locpath) VALUES (4,'la2')
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain the aversion to `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to select rows from [locations] and order the results by the number of rows are associated with each location in [location_photos]

You can use a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select l.*
from locations l
order by (select count(*) 
          from location_photos lp
          where lp.location_id = l.id
         ) desc;
```

If you want the count in the query as well as the ordering criterion, just move the subquery to the `select`:

```
select l.*,
       (select count(*) 
        from location_photos lp
        where lp.location_id = l.id
       ) as num_photos
from locations l
order by num_photos desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want aggregation:

```
SELECT l.id, count(lp.locationid) AS cnt_photos, l.title
FROM locations l
LEFT JOIN location_photos lp on lp.locationid = l.id
GROUP BY l.id, l.title
ORDER BY cnt_photos desc
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery to count the matching photos. Here is one way to do it with a lateral join:

```
select l.*, lp.*
from locations l
cross apply (select count(*) cnt_photos from location_photos lp where lp.locationid = l.id) lp
ORDER BY lp.cnt_photos desc
```